# Youtube live streaming getting stuck in Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am using [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for android to display youtube videos in my app. Normal videos stream very well, but youtube live streaming videos get stuck after few minutes in certain hardwares. These live streaming videos even got stuck when played usiing youtube app within these devices, while were playing completely fine using chrome browser.

Once initialized, I use the following line to play any youtube video:

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo(id);
```

My queries are the following ?

1. What streaming protocol does youtube use for live streaming within Android ? Is it different with chrome browser and youtube app ?
2. What can be done to enable my app with seamless youtube live streaming ?

P.S. All my devices I have tested use Android version 4.4+